# REST API remove contact from journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder, array

I'm using this REST API JSON call to remove a subscriber from a journey:

```
[
{
"ContactKey": "0031xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"DefinitionKey": "cexxxxxx-b20f-74ea-c67a-xxxx7c53xxxx",
"Versions": [0,1,2,3]
}
]
```

It works like a charm, but I'm unsure on the use of the array for the versions of the journey.
The [documentation for the /interaction/v1/interactions/contactexit API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/contactExitRequest.htm) only states, that this needs to be an array.
As I have three versions of the journey today, my solution is *[0,1,2,3]*, but in stead I'd like a more flexible solution that always removes contacts from every version of the journey.

What are my options when using the array for referencing versions of a journey?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The versions array is optional. I you don't specify this property, the contact is removed from all versions of the journey concerned:

```
POST /interaction/v1/interactions/contactexit
[
    {
        "ContactKey": "0031xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "DefinitionKey": "cexxxxxx-b20f-74ea-c67a-xxxx7c53xxxx"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest solution that comes to mind - do an API call before your original call that would be asking in which journey version this contact is.

You can do that with the following endpoint:

[POST /interaction/v1/interactions/contactMembership](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/contactMembershipRequest.htm)

Comment: Thank you Rafal. This is useful knowledge too :)